# Drag and drop with 2 drop target

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I am looking for an example of drag and drop where the drag item has two distinct areas that have to match up with two droppable areas.

Example:
[image]

I would like the blue drag item to revert unless it is dropped in a position where each of its red children land on a green area.

Ideally I would like to use jquery ui (as I have experience with it), but any javascript library would be fine, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a combination of `draggable`/`droppable` options.  Given HTML like this:

```
<div id="blue" class="valid">
    <div id="red-one" class="red"></div>
    <div id="red-two" class="red"></div>
</div>

<div id="green-container">
    <div id="green-one" class="green">
    </div>
    <div id="green-two" class="green">
    </div>
</div>
```

(omitting CSS, I did add some rules, see in the fiddle below).

You can write JavaScript like this:

```
function isInside(one, other) {
    return one.offset().left >= other.offset().left &&
        one.offset().top >= other.offset().top &&
        one.offset().top + one.height() <= other.offset().top + other.height() &&
        one.offset().left + one.width() <= other.offset().left + other.width();
}

$("#blue").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $reds = $this.children(".red");
        var $greens = $("#green-container").children(".green");
        var firstRed = $reds.first();
        var firstGreen = $greens.first();
        var secondRed = $reds.last();
        var secondGreen = $greens.last();

        if (isInside(firstRed, firstGreen) && isInside(secondRed, secondGreen)) {
            $this.addClass('valid');
        }
        else {
            $this.removeClass('valid');
        }       
    },
    revert: 'invalid'
});


$("#green-container").droppable({ accept: ".valid" });
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/g6FKz/

**Notes:**

- For some reason I had to apply the 'valid' class initially to the 'blue' div, or else the target droppable would not accept the dragged element, even if it was valid (would appreciate some input on this).  Not sure what's up with that, might be a bug in jQueryUI.  Not a huge deal though.
- The target droppable isn't exactly the two green elements, it's a white `div` that contains those elements.  This should be clear from the example.
- Every time you move the draggable `div`, the "drag" event is called, which determines if the red boxes are inside the green ones and assigns a `valid` class to the draggable `div`.  The droppable object only accepts `valid` draggables.

Hope that helps!

Comment: +1 for fantastically detailed answer and working JSfiddle example, thanks

Comment: `You can write **JQuery** like this`